# Old MacBook air's trackpad's right click is failing, is there a workaround gesture?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, multi-touch

My old MacBook Air is old.

I have to push hard to get right click to work. It is probably something mechanical that could be addressed at a service center.

But in the mean time, is there anything I can do in MacOS to assign some gesture or combination of a gesture plus a key to do what right click does?

I use right click mostly to open little menus (e.g. to edit some object), open url in new tab, etc.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  Left Click is the standard replacement for Right Click.

Alternatively, on a trackpad you could enable 2-finger click from System Prefs

[image]

Comment: Oh this works so nicely, *thank you!* I should have thought to ask a year ago.